# Image Alt and Title Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, accessibility, image

I have a client who hates the tooltips shown in browsers by the alt and title attributes of images. They requested they be removed. Obviously this is an issue for both SEO and Accessibility.

While the accessibility thing is not a huge deal to me, the SEO factor is. My initial thoughts are to remove the alt and title attributes of the images with a quick JS script. Anyone see any issues with that?

Comment: The "accessibility" thing should be a huge deal for you. It's the law. http://www.section508.gov/

Comment: is this help to you ? http://dotjay.co.uk/2007/apr/removing-alt-tooltips-in-ie-with-javascript

Comment: alt text is an accessibility requirement and most browsers won't show the text on hover.  The title will be shown on hover.

Comment: Because the title attribute is not a requirement, you could remove it. But do not remove the alt text.

Comment: It seems the laws on accessibility only apply to federal/government websites. Although it is recommended that all follow them.

Comment: Chrome shows the ALT tag on hover

Comment: Just as a pointer: Section 508 might be law only where *you* are (the rest of the world may have similar laws though, and accessibility is massively important, and should be promoted, regardless of local legislation...)

Comment: Tell your client that "sorry, I can't reinvent the internet for you"

Comment: As for the law, yea, there are loopholes, but you can easily pitch it as "not addressing accessibility is just another liability opening you up to potential lawsuits"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alt` and `title` attributes are two different things.

The `alt` attribute is used for accessibility reasons and is required by the standards set by the W3C. In the United States, it's also part of the Section 508 laws and regulations. The `alt` attribute behaves poorly in older versions of Internet Explorer by showing it's contents via a tooltip. I know for a fact Internet Explorer 9 no longer has this behavior.

The `title` attribute is used to force the browser in to showing a tooltip with it's contents.

My advice to you is use the `alt` attribute exclusively instead of the `title` attribute. Advise your client to update their browser to a more standards compliant browser if a tooltip irks them that much.

Modern screen readers read the generated DOM. This means if you remove tags via JavaScript, you are not only invalidating your code after the fact, you are possibily hurting those who will visiting the site using assistive technology.

I highly recommend you don't do it.

**More information**
Target was sued and settled because of the `alt` attribute: http://www.sitepoint.com/target-settles-accessibility-lawsuit-for-6-million/

Because of this landmark case, it's safe to say that Section 508 **DOES NOT** only apply to federal and government websites.

Comment: Thanks again Michael. Do you know where I can find more info on U.S law regarding web site accessibility? I could only find legal precedent regulating federal sites using your previous link.

Comment: @Michael, can you explain "Section 508 DOES NOT only apply to federal and government websites" a bit more? Certainly you're not saying that section 508 applies to every website that's created (even if it should)?

Comment: I know there's a ton of information on that site I linked you, albeit hard to navigate. You can check out Cythia Says: http://www.cynthiasays.com/. It's like a validator for accessibility. Also, the University of Illinois has a great accessibility validator as well: http://fae.cita.uiuc.edu/. It goes a little further because the State of Illinois has a little bit more stricter rules, but they're all good practices to get in the habit of because in the long run, they make your site that much more accessible by everyone.

Comment: @Quickfire55 Before the case against Target in 2006, I would agree with you in saying not every site needs to follow the ADA and Section 508 regulations. That case changed it. If you don't follow them, will you get sued? Probably not, but all it takes is one person to change that. If you're in the US, you want to follow these regulations. If not only for the CYA factor, but for the fact that you WANT traffic to your site, why wouldn't you take the time to make sure you're not turning people away because of their disabilities?

Comment: @Michael, I don't disagree that accessibility should be something we all strive for, but I do disagree that the Target case changed everything. Target settled (a PR move IMHO), therefore no legal precedent has been set. Anyone can sue anyone in the US - it's the American way.

Comment: The fact that they settled means they realized they'd likely lose the case.

Comment: @DA, again, I disagree. The fact that they settled means that they had a very wise PR team. What company in their right mind wouldn't settle? What would their defense be - "We have every right to ignore the handicapped!"?

Answer (score 2):

**If** accessibility is not an issue, I see no issues using JavaScript to remove the content. Assuming you're OK with using jQuery, this is the easiest way in my opinion:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});
```

You could also remove the title content in the onmouseover event and then add it back on the onmouseout event for the sake of SEO.

Comment: Well considering most all search engines do not read Javascript fully (yet), I don't think I need to add it back. Although would be a good idea to comply with the future of search engine spiders.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JavaScript, you could use:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    images[i].removeAttribute('title');
    images[i].removeAttribute('alt');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GQMMY/2/).

Reference:

- [`removeAttribute()` at the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider if you want to remove these features only under certain circumstances. I experience a lot of similar ideas in daily business, because some people do not like to understand what certain things a good for, and maybe handle them by themselves ...

... which brings me to the idea to eventually add a Greasemonkey script, which provides the desired functionality instead of worsening the website by means of accessibility, etc. At least it should be an additionally configurable option, maybe by setting a cookie or stuff like that.

Maybe you can convince the client it is a better than getting rid of something, to allow to make everyone the choice for their own, and activate the default settings for best SEO and accessibility.